# Не запускается эмулятор android studio Can't find 'Linux version ' string in kernel image file

Tags: android, android-studio, эмулятор, android-emulator, avd

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]У меня Windows 7. В Android Studio запускаю эмулятор и выдает следующую ошибку:

> 6:40  Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Can't find 'Linux version ' string in
> kernel image file:
> C:\Users\BBd\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-30\google_apis\x86`\\`kernel-ranchu-64

Сам файл по этому пути есть. Но в этом пути в конце используется две косые `\\`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где можно исправить сам путь?

Comment: Как обновить эмулятор до 30 версии? Я удалил 28 и дали установить только 28 версию эмулятора.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можно попробовать:

```
Tools > SDK Manager > SDK Tools > Android Emulator > Mark it checked to force update > Accept
```

[Вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43089302/emulator-cant-find-linux-version-string-in-kernel-image-file) есть подобная проблема. Обсуждения [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60319486/android-emulator-api-24-cant-start-due-to-kernel-image-file-kernel-ranchu) и [2](https://www.programmersought.com/article/68055642903/).